# Telegram Bot send message without user interaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram, telegram-bot

I've been searching in a couple of topics here about this matter but I can't seem to get it right for Java.

#### QUESTION:

How can I send a message from my bot without the enduser having to start any conversation or have any kind of interaction?

Comment: Telegram Bot API explicitly prohibits messaging *from* bot to normal users without dialog start from user.  Doesn't matter which language was used for implementation.

Comment: How about sending a message to a specific user from a group? for instance, I have a group with 1000 people and then i choose one random to send a message

Answer (score -1):

If you use C#, you Can use **telegram.api** and below code:

```
bot.sendMessage.send(bot.chat_id,"Your Message").ToString();
```

Comment: what is that bot.sendMessage ? what package is that?

Comment: @user9656138 , packages\Telegram.dll.6.4.2\lib\Telegram.dll

Comment: i'll have to search the equivalent (if there is one) to java. i'll get back to you once I have news. thank you :)